# How to extend javascript library through plugins?

Tags: javascript, plugins, callback, extend

Say i want to develop a library that will keep a very small core and may be extended through plugins.

So i basically came up with something in the scale of:

```
(function(window){
     window.SomeLibrary =(function(){
          var api = { 
              init: function(){
                  console.log('hi');
                  privateFunction();
                },
              plugin: function(callback) {
                  callback.call();
                }
            };
          var privateFunction = function() {
            console.log('im a private method');
            };
        return api;
        }());
    })(window);

SomeLibrary.init();
SomeLibrary.plugin(function(){
    console.log('im a plugin');
    privateFunction(); //fails;    
});
```

How can i make the plugin callback executes SomeLibrary private and public methods?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn’t the whole idea with a private function that it should NOT be accessible outside it’s scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can collect your private functions in an object and pass this object to the extending plugin.

```
Lib.extend('pluginName',function(privates){
    //I have access to privateJob via privates.privateJob();
});
```

then in lib:

```
var privateCollection = {                 //your private collecting object
    privateJob : function(){...}          //a private function
}

extend : function(pluginName,callback){ //an extend function that receives callback
    callback(privateCollection);          //execute callback with private collection
}
```

but access to inner functions is a bad idea. this WILL wreck the internals of your library.

Comment: Thanks for that :) really cool solution, while it also allows me to encapsulate only some methods for plugin access. Thanks again :)

Comment: How would you register these plugins so they can be called like Lib.pluginName(); ??

Comment: @CarlosBarbosa one way you can do it is to attach them to the `Lib` object. Then, just like jQuery, every jQuery object contains library methods plus the plugin methods. I suggest you take a look on how jQuery gets extended.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. That's why they are **private**. They are not accessible from outside the scope.

If you expose some references to those methods, you need to treat those functions as properties or `SomeLibrary`, which means they are not private anymore.

Or you can use [closure](http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/rg36/index.html) to achieve similar results. But I don't think it's **private** either.

Answer (score 0):

The `privateFunction` is not in the scope for the callback.
By using a closure you can make the function available for plugins, without providing it in the `api`, but the function will not be **private**.

For example:

```
(function(window){
 window.SomeLibrary =(function(){
         var privateFunction = function() {
            console.log('im a private method');
        };
         var init = function(){
              console.log('hi');
              privateFunction();
            };
          var plugin = function(){ 
              var pluginScope={
                  privateFunction :privateFunction,
              };
              return function(callback) {
                  callback(pluginScope);
               }
          }();
          var api = { 
              init: init,
              plugin: plugin
          };
    return api;
    }());
})(window);

SomeLibrary.init();
SomeLibrary.plugin(function(scope){
    console.log('im a plugin ');
    scope.privateFunction();;    
});​
```

You can test it at http://jsfiddle.net/uXppZ/2/